# Remove PROCESS_TERMINATE access right from process, created by CreateProcessWithLogonW

Tags: c++, windows, security, winapi, process

I am using the following code to create process with security rights of other user:

```
CreateProcessWithLogonW(
    Username,
    Domain ? Domain : L".",
    Password,
    LOGON_WITH_PROFILE,
    ApplicationName,
    CommandLine,
    CREATE_SUSPENDED | CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT,
    Environment,
    CurrentDirectory,
    &StartupInfo,
    ProcessInfo);
```

But this process can use [TerminateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to kill the calling process. I've read that I have to remove [PROCESS_TERMINATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684880%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) access right from this process, but I was unable to find information how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spawned process handle is returned in the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` struct.  Pass it to [`GetSecurityInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to retrieve the process's SACL/DACL, construct a new one that denies `PROCESS_TERMINATE`, and then call [`SetSecurityInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379588%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to apply it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. To be honest I was looking for more detailed example.

Comment: @kjen93, if you are looking for more details in an answer, then you should amend your question to include the code that you've tried and request more help.